# CEN/XFS - Invalid Pointer

Tags: java, dll, jna, cen-xfs

i implementing new Service Provider with CEN-XFS, but it's returning error, (-26), equal this "WFS_ERR_INVALID_POINTER".

I use java, more precisely JNA to communicate with the DLL (msxfs.dll).

I Create service provider with REGEDIT on [HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\XFS\LOGICAL_SERVICES\MyCurrencyDispenser] 
with values:

[Regedit image...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr7wN.png)

My interface - WFSOpen (its part to LibraryMethods).

```
public short WFSOpen(String lpszLogicalName, int hApp, String lpszAppID, 
int dwTraceLevel, int dwTimeOut, int dwSrvcVersionsRequired,
String lpSrvcVersion, String lpSPIVersion, String lpRequestID);
```

WFSOpen execute after WFSStartUp..

```
hResult = libMethods.WFSOpen("MyCurrencyDispenser", 0, "CDM", 0x0000001F, 0,
dwVersionsRequired, lpWFSVersionOld, lpWFSVersion, null);
```

WFSOpen native:

```
HRESULT extern WINAPI WFSOpen(LPSTR lpszLogicalName, HAPP hApp, LPSTR 
lpszAppID, DWORD dwTraceLevel, DWORD dwTimeOut, DWORD 
dwSrvcVersionsRequired, LPWFSVERSION lpSrvcVersion, LPWFSVERSION 
lpSPIVersion, LPHSERVICE lphService);
```

I need help, thank's..

Comment: `WFSOpen` is your JNA "wrapper" for native `WFSOpen` method. Right?

Comment: Yes man, is correct

Comment: Seems like you wrote invalid wrapper. Can you add signature of native method to the question?

Comment: Ok, i edited......really, that methods are language C/C++, but i use JNA with communicate to DLL, so types primitives equals " HSERVICE hService " no have alternative, i have to create String HSERVICE, you understand ?

Comment: LPWFSVERSION lpSrvcVersion - is a pointer to structure, LPWFSVERSION lpSPIVersion - also is a pointer to stucture, LPHSERVICE lphService - is a pointer to HSERVICE which is DWORD sized. You can try to use jna api Pointer to get this values. This values cannot be converted to a strings.

Comment: When i using Pointer, ByteBuffer, ShortByReference...etc types equals use String or Int... :(

Answer (score 0):

The below error tells you, your `pointer` points to wrong memory which `WFSOPEN()` function needed.

```
"WFS_ERR_INVALID_POINTER"
```

one of your `struct` or `HAPP` parameter need to be pointed correctly.

```
notice: HAPP is void* not integer type.
```